# Telnet not recognized though installed

Tags: windows-7

I have the message command not recognized though I checked in control that it was installed as explained here:

http://www.question-defense.com/2010/07/23/windows-7-telnet-is-not-recognized-as-an-internal-or-external-command

Is there something else like registry settings?

Comment: can you see if it is installed by finding if telnet.exe is available under c:\windows subdirectory?
Then try to execute it giving full path. And post the results.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem and it turned out I had the windows support tools installed. These were using a 64 bit command shell, and it wouldn't run the 32 bit binary of telnet (I am guessing.) Check the properties of your shortcut. If it is in the sysWOW64 folder, you are using the wrong command shell. You need the one in the system32 folder.

Answer (score 0):

Try to uninstall it (go back to the control panel as explained in the link you posted, uncheck it and apply the change) then re-install it.
*make sure you mark Telnet Client, and not Telnet Server.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I had to go to the `System32` directory to be able to execute it. Why `System32` is not in the path, I don't know.

Comment: You can add it back in Environment Variables if its missing.